# WPF MVVM - Send dynamic parameter to parent ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm creating a WPF application that will create an arbitrary number of circles in a Canvas. The user should be able to click a specific circle to "select" it, causing the circle to grow larger. Other GUI elements will also update with other data in the ViewModel for that circle.

The trick is that I need to be able to unselect all other circles when one is selected, so the circle VM itself can't handle the select method. I need the parent VM to be able to handle it - and I need to pass an ID of the specific circle that was clicked as a parameter. (I have this ID property created already in the circle VM.)

Here's what I've got so far:

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ClientManagerVM/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="Scroller" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Background="Black" Grid.RowSpan="1">
            <Canvas x:Name="DrawingCanvas" Height="{Binding circlesVM.Height, Mode=OneWay}" Width="{Binding circlesVM.Width, Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Black">
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding circlesVM.circleList}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <Canvas />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding x}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding y}"/>
                        </Style>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Ellipse Fill="White" Width="{Binding size, Mode=OneWay}" Height="{Binding size, Mode=OneWay}">
                                <Ellipse.InputBindings>
                                    <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick" />
                                </Ellipse.InputBindings>
                            </Ellipse>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </Canvas>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

How can I set up the MouseBinding inside my Ellipse to trigger a command in the ClientManagerVM with a parameter value of the ID of the specific Ellipse?

Comment: I suggest you switch to `ListBox` instead of `ItemsControl` because ListBox has selection support out-of-box. Also MouseBinding has bindable Command and CommandParameter properties which should be enough to bind and trigger a command

Answer (score 0):

Something like this where `YourCommand` is an `ICommand` property of the "circlesVM" that accepts a circle as a command parameter:

```
<Ellipse Fill="White" Width="{Binding size, Mode=OneWay}" Height="{Binding size, Mode=OneWay}">
    <Ellipse.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick"
                      Command="{Binding DataContext.circlesVM.YourCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"
                      CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
    </Ellipse.InputBindings>
</Ellipse>
```